# Vim Surround command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I have trouble remembering all the various keywords in vim.  However, things like 'surround' from Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin are very useful.

Is it possible to set up a generic text command such  that when I execute something like

```
 :surround (.)
```

it will replace the current selection with

```
 (<current_selection>)
```

or if I execute

```
  :surround preamble.somethingelse
```

It will replace the current selection with:

```
preamble<current_selection>somethingelse
```

Comment: Please have a look at the github page of the plugin. There is a mode for visual selection

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I think his point is that it's all too complex to remember. (Also, vim-surround doesn't allow you to surround with arbitrary text pair, unless you engage in `surround-customizing`.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Amadan. But as far as I can see `surround` in visual mode allows arbitrary text pairs. Have a look at the `S` shortcut. For non visual there is always [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich). Remembering is more or less straight forward `surround` -> `s`, `change surrounding` -> `cs` and so on... But it takes some time if you are new to vim.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: I don't know what you mean by the first sentence; I don't know a way other than `surround-customizing` to surround with `preamble....somethingelse` (e.g. change `foo` to `<!-- foo -->`, or `bar(foo)`). (And yes, I agree, remembering is a matter of practice.)

Comment: @Armadan had another look, it seems to only be possible for synchronous text or xthml tags, but visually selection text and then pressing `S<p class="important">`  for example will work

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes, because a tag is a defined replacement. You can't, AFAIK, make up an ad-hoc replacement pair to surround with. (This is in practice not such a great disadvantage; I use another plugin for commenting, and prefixing parentheses with a method name can be done using pure Vim without too much discomfort.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202715/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-amadan).

Answer (score 2):

Almost, yes.

```
:command! -range -nargs=1 Surround normal gv"zc<args><Esc>F.v"zp
```

With this, you can create a visual selection, then use

```
:Surround (.)
:Surround preamble.somethingelse
```

Note that user-defined commands can never start with a lowercase letter, so `:surround` that you ask for is *not* possible. Also, this is a quick hack, so it's rather fragile.

However, as per comments, I would urge you to use more standard Vim methods (and well-vetted plugins like surround.vim) before cooking up custom ways to use it.

Here's another way, using surround plugin: define a custom replacement and perform it (then fix the plugin config to what it was before):

```
command! -range -nargs=1 Surround call ArbitrarySurround(<q-args>)
function! ArbitrarySurround(repl)
  let backup = b:surround_45
  let b:surround_45 = substitute(a:repl, "\\.", "\r", "")
  norm gvS-
  let b:surround_45 = backup
endfunction
```

This is more robust than the previous one, allowing ad-hoc custom replacement pairs, but does require the surround plugin. It can be used with the same syntax as the above one.

Comment: I was just about to add an alternative answer that would implement OP's ask without the surround plugin when I saw that you had already done exactly that. I also agree that while this satisfies the OP's requirements, it would be better to rely on a plugin, especially if one is not well versed in Vim scripting yet.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a custom "surrounding" which will prompt you for the text:

```
let g:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "\1start: \1\r\2end: \2"
```

Now you can visually select what you want to wrap and then press `S-` to tigger the `-` surrounding. It will then prompt you for a "start" and "ending" text.

For more help see:

```
:h surround-customizing
:h char2nr()
:h curly-brace-names
```

Comment: This solves 90% of my surrounding needs without a plugin. Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to leverage the surround.vim plugin, you have to base your customization on what the plugin offers. For visual mode, it's basically this mapping (that by default is mapped to `S`):

```
vnoremap <silent> <Plug>VSurround  :<C-U>call <SID>opfunc(visualmode(),visualmode() ==# 'V' ? 1 : 0)<CR>
```

The plugin does not expose any functions (the `<SID>opfunc()` it invokes is script-local), so you have to invoke the `<Plug>`-mapping; that can easily be done with `:normal` (without a `[!]`).

Also, the plugin only takes a single character (e.g. `(` to surround with parens and whitespace, `)` to surround with just parens); you can reference that in your custom command via [`<args>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Cargs%3E).

You create a custom command with [`:help :command`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand); note that the command has to start with an uppercase letter:

```
command! -nargs=+ Surround execute "normal gv\<Plug>VSurround" . <q-args>
```

This re-enters visual mode (`gv`), then invokes the plugin, and finally supplies the passed argument. In order to directly invoke it from visual mode, just add a `-range` to the definition, so that the command takes (and ignores) the `'<,'>` range that Vim automatically supplies then.

You can then invoke the new custom command as `:Surround )`, for example, and it will surround the previous visual selection with `(`...`)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked, but since the problem is memorizing, how about putting this in your .vimrc:

```
vmap ( o<ESC>i(<ESC>gvo<ESC>a)<ESC>
vmap " o<ESC>i"<ESC>gvo<ESC>a"<ESC>
```

Make your selection, hit <kbd>(</kbd> and it gets surrounded with `(` `)`.

Make your selection, hit <kbd>"</kbd> and it gets surrounded with `"` `"`.

You could do the same with `{`, `[` or `'`. For such a simple use-case there's no real need for a plugin.